# Use windows username in html

Tags: javascript, html, variables, desktop

I was experimenting with using a .htm file as a desktop background and i wanted to make it so it would say something like "Welcome, 'username'!" where 'username' would be my username that i use to log on to my computer. I have a windows xp computer if that makes a difference. I do not have much experience with javascript, but with some searching i think i found something to use to get the username:

```
<script language="javascript">
function GetUserName()
{
    var wshell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    alert(wshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%"));
}
</script>
```

I just found that on the web, i am not sure which part is the acquired username...
What i need is to use this later in my html to display on my wallpaper: "Welcome, 'username'!" I am not sure if it is needed, but i will include it anyways, the html code i want the welcome statement would be in

```
<center><div class="widget"><div class="title"> *welcome statement here* </div></div></center>
```

Alright thanks guys!!

Comment: Does the `alert` work? If so, select your `title` element (`document.querySelector(".widget .title")`, maybe? I’d give it an ID – not sure which browser engine Active Desktop uses) and put the returned value in its `innerHTML`. (Or, better, create a text node and append it…)

Comment: fyi that won't work in non-ie browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Give your title DIV an ID:

```
<center><div class="widget"><div class="title" id="welcome"> Welcome </div></div></center>
```

Then use the following Javascript:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var username = GetUserName();
    document.getElementById('welcome').innerHTML = 'Welcome, '+username;
});

function GetUserName() {
    var wshell = ActiveXObject && new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    return wshell && wshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%");
}
```

Comment: only works with IE , it needs other plugins for FF and Chrome

Comment: Since the original question is about ActiveX, which is an IE-only technology, I took that as a given.

Comment: And the `%USERNAME%` environment variable is Windows-only.

Comment: Just trying this out with IE 11  , I get       Welcome, function ActiveXObject() { [native code] }    spitting out on the page

Comment: @TomStickel That would happen if `GetUserName()` ended with `return wshell;` instead of `return wshell && wshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%");`